# Java cmd's active directory

Tags: java, cmd, directory

I want to know cmd's active working directory in a java console application.

For example, I'm running command in console like below:

```
C:\users\myuser> java -jar D:\apps\application.jar
```

and I want to know

```
C:\users\myuser
```

How can I get this?

Thx for replies

Answer (score 0):

[`user.dir`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) will give you working directory:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Comment: That is right. This is a folder where is your app started.

Comment: But I want to know cmd's current path

Comment: The current path is the one where your app stars : D:\apps\! If you want another path then you are not looking for the "current path"

Comment: I don't know where I wrong. According to my hypothesis, cmd's current path is 'C:\users\myuser' and my application location is 'D:\apps\application.jar' and console looking that the given url is absolute or available cmd's current path. If this hypothesis is valid, then I can obtain **cmd's** current path. If not, where I am wrong about my hypothesis. Can you explain?

Comment: I am not into Windows that much, so you can check this: http://superuser.com/questions/396394/how-do-i-set-an-executables-working-directory-via-the-command-line-prior-to-ex

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this :

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

**user.dir** is a System property allowing to find it.
You can find the list of all available system property [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)